# Best and efficient way to sort incoming logs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We have a array of log sources, in which each log have a schema like:

```
{
    serviceName: serviceA, 
    reason: '', 
    time: UTC
}
```

And these logs in each log source will be in chronological order. Now given millions of log sources, we wanted to sort all them and print on `stdout` in chronological order.

I'm wondering which data structure can be used here to address this problem.

I thought the following:

1. Take all log sources and sort them based on first element.
2. Now run through first log source and compare with next log source first element and print until we find the next greater time
3. Repeat the 1, 2 steps.

But wanted to see if any other data structures helps here.

Comment: You know most of the algorithm has `O(N log n)` complexity But you can use hash data structure to reduce time complexity to `O(n)`

Comment: How many total log lines are we talking here? It seems like if you have millions of log files, then you may end up with billions of lines. I'm not sure how outputing them to stdout can make sense...

Comment: Is this a real problem, or an exercise?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi - a hash is not appropriate for sorted (or chronological) data?

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you have step 1 when you said "each log source will be in chronological order"? If each log is already sorted, you just merge them. No more sorting needed.

Answer (score 2):

The standard structure for this would be a [priority queue, also known as a "heap"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)); it can efficiently keep track of the smallest element.

1. Take all log sources and convert the list of them into a heap based on first element.
2. Peek at the first source on the heap, emit one element from it.
3. If the source is not exhausted, re-establish the heap property based on its next element (if you're using a library, this may be called a "pop+push" operation). If the source is exhausted, pop it off the heap.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the heap is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary to hold the different services and then from each source add a list of logs from this source (they are already in sorted order). Finally merge the lists for each service.

pseudo code

```
loglist = {}
for (source in sources)
  services = {}

  for (log in source)
    services[log.serviceName].append(log)

  for (name, list in services)
    loglist[name].append(list)

for (name, lists in loglist)
  list = merge(lists) // according to UTC, use the merge from merge-sort
  print name
  print list
```

No sorting required.

Comment: Will there any problem for merging since there are more than 2 lists to merge from? Will we eventually need sorting here?

Comment: @LongNguyen if you merge them two at a time so you half the number of lists each time you should get the optimal merging and since the merge with the UTC time as value they will be place in the correct order. This requires that the individual sources are sorted from the start.

Comment: Sounds right to me, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Because the logs are already sorted individually, all you need to do is to merge them. That is the [merge step](https://www.happycoders.eu/algorithms/merge-sort/#Merge_Sort_Merge_Example) of a merge sort. You don't need a special data structure other than a list of your records.

Basic algorithm:

```
var list = new list of records
do
   minValue = beginningOfTime
   foreach (item in sources)  
       if (item.Timestamp >= minValue)   ​
     ​      set minValue = item.Timestamp
           increment currentItem for source[n]
           if source[n] has no more values
               remove source[n] from sources
   add minValue to list

until no more sources
```

I will say things could get more complicated in the sense that I am ignoring buffering, parallelism, async I/O and other concerns. This answer is about the algorithm and data structure.

Comment: Emitting each record will be O(k) for k sources with this approach, while it's only O(log k) using a heap